# Do Windows services have elevated privileges?

Tags: windows, services, privileges

If I create a service with nssm using nssm install, does that service run with admin permissions? If so, how can I revoke that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on which user you specify on the Log On tab

> nssm will automatically ensure that the account you choose has the necessary log on as a service permissions

[image]

You can either choose a different service account on this tab, or use the defaults and change the user from `services.msc`. Right-click the service, select Properties, and then navigate to the Log On tab

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't *depend entirely on which user you specify on the Log On tab*.
Even if the user has administrator rights, there are two ways to run common applications:

- normally
- "Run as administrator" (with elevated privileges)

The question from the initial post is, here both methods can be used even when starting the service via NSSM.
A similar service startup tool, AlwaysUp, introduced the option:
**Launch the application without admin rights**
https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/onedrive/windows-service-not-deleting-files/#resolution
I would need a similar option for NSSM.